# TreeMap using a string key and an arraylist

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, treemap

I am brand new to using collections, so I am confused on how to do this.  I am trying to use a TreeMap to hold a word as the key and then an ArrayList to hold one or more definitions for the word.

```
public class Dict {
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> dic = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public void AddCmd(String word, String def) {
        System.out.println("Add Cmd " + word);
        if(dic.get(word)==null){
            dic.put(word, new ArrayList.add(def));      
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on "`new ArrayList.add(def)`".  I thought this was the correct way to do this, but I am obviously wrong.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`ArrayList#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) returns a `boolean` which is not the desired value for your `Map`, thus getting the compiler error.

You need to insert the `ArrayList` and then add the element. Your code should look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> definitions = dic.get(word);
if (definitions == null) {
    definitions = new ArrayList<String>();
    dic.put(word, definitions);
}
definitions.add(def);
```

Answer (score 1):

dic.put(word, new ArrayList.add(def)); is the culprit.
since you have declared map to take Arraylist of string as a value. the value to pass for map must be Arraylist of string.

but this line is adding a value as new ArrayList.add(def) since you are trying to create a list and adding element , add method returns boolean -> true if it can add false if it fails.

so it means value to the map is going as a boolean not as arraylist which is against the map declaration.
so use code as below

```
ArrayList<String> listOfString = dic.get(word);
if (listOfString == null) {
    listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfString .add(def);
}
dic.put(word, listOfString );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to break it up, because `add` does not return the original ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String>> NewList = new ArrayList<String>();
NewList.add(def);
dic.put(word, NewList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually creating a new ArrayList. Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> newDef = new ArrayList<String();
newDef.add(def);
dic.put(word, newDef);
```